# MySQL Unread Result with Python

Tags: python, mysql

I use mysql.connector to do SQL operations.
I have a short scripts which executes the following operations (strings) on the cursor with `cursor.execute(...)`:

```
"use {}".format(db)

"show tables"

command = """
ALTER TABLE Object DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE Object ADD `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST;
ALTER TABLE Object ADD INDEX (`uid`);"""
```

The script iterates over several databases `db`.

The problem is that at some point I get an "Unread result found" error. It seems when I run the script, at some point "use mydb" returns a result (cursor._have_result=True), when I didn't expect one. The weird thing is that if I rerun the full script it runs a little longer with more databases giving the same error later.

Can you suggest a way to solve or investigate this problem? Is there something I can do to prevent "unread results"?

PS: When I rerun the script the ALTER commands fails for the databases which are already done. Not sure if that causes problems.

Comment: Can you pl refer this http://geert.vanderkelen.org/buffering-results-with-mysql-connectorpython/? Not sure if this is the same reason why you are getting "Unread results found" error.

Comment: Not sure if the same issue, but I've found that issuing a command that consists of several heavy long-running queries may result in an issue similar to your. Try splitting your `command` in three separate statements.

Comment: @DJV: I've split the commands and now it ran without errors. Thanks! Not sure how to explain this.

Comment: @Gerenuk I encountered a similar error when using multiple statements in alters and updates of tables with several hundreds of thousands of entries. Something about asynchronous executions, maybe? Not really sure.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using MySQL Connector/Python, the *Unread results found* might happen when you use the connection object in different places without reading the result. It's not something one can go around. You can use the [*buffered* option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html) to read result immediately.

As mentioned in the comments, it's best to split the statements and execute them separately.

If you want to execute multiple statements, you'll need to use the [*multi=True* option for the MySQLCursor.execute()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/myconnpy_MySQLCursor_execute.html) method (since Connector/Python v1.0.4). Actually, if you don't use the *multi* option and send multiple statements, an InterfaceError will raise. (I do suspect a bug here as well..)

Additional remarks:

- Instead of executing the USE-command to change databases, you can [MySQLConnection.database property](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-python-apiref-MySQLConnection.html#myconnpy_MySQLConnection_database).
- You best group the changes into one ALTER TABLE statement, like this:

  ALTER TABLE t1 DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT KEY FIRST, ADD INDEX(c1)

Comment: How does one go about avoiding this error without the `buffered` option? AFAIK you read results using `MySQLCursor.description` - is there another method I'm supposed to be using instead?

Comment: @sorbet: The only way would be to close the connection and reconnect. No, results are not read when getting description.

Comment: why exactly can't MySQL connector/python *discard* unread results when not buffering?  buffering is a huge performance issue but without the ability to discard remaining data, it's not feasible to turn it off.  OurSQL does not have this issue.

Comment: #geertjanvdk Could you clarify what you mean by using the connection in different places without "reading the result"? I'm having a similar issue, but im not trying to issue multiple commands at once like the original poster.

Comment: @zzzeek: you can not simply tell the MySQL server to forget the result if you just use plain queries. There is some way around that using prepared statements (what OurSQL is doing). If you don't want the result, strongly opt to select less if possible.

Comment: @Wilson: missing to read one row from a result is already going to trigger the error. Connections in multiple places: for example sharing the connection object between threads.

Comment: @geertjanvdk there's a difference between reading the buffer plainly, e.g. read(), and discarding that data, vs. taking all the data from that read(), parsing it into in-Python result rows, unpacking all the data in each column, etc.   In Python without C-level processing this is hugely expensive.

Comment: @zzzeek: True. There are some changes around this with consuming result in Connector/Python 2.1 (was implemented while adding C Extension).

Answer (score 5):

You have to pass `buffered = true` in your cursor. Read more official [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-tutorial-cursorbuffered.html)

```
cursor = conn.cursor(buffered=True)
```