# updating mysql field unread result found

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to update a specific field in a table with the current date/time using mysql connector.

First, I had retrieved a row from the table which works fine but when I try to update a field it runs into a problem.

```
dbu.cursor.execute("""
UPDATE
    Clients
SET
    backup_started=NOW()
WHERE
    company_name= %s""",(company_name, ))
dbu.cnx.commit()
```

The error I am getting is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sysadmin/Documents/backup.py", line 98, in <module>
    company_name= %s""",(company_name, ))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 476, in execute
    raise errors.InternalError("Unread result found.")
  InternalError: Unread result found.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Bigger piece of your code might be needed but I can try...
Are you using the connection from multiple places (e.g. from multiple threads)? I have a similar problem and while I wasn't able to solve it yet, the following answer might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17268389

Also this article by the same author might be useful to you:
http://geert.vanderkelen.org/buffering-results-with-mysql-connectorpython/