# mysql/python 'unread result found' when insert result into table

Tags: python, mysql, database

I have a 'relatively' large table 200,000 rows in my my original table. If I run my 1st query without buffered=true like below. I can see both the printed message 'aaa' and 'bbb'. However I can only see 1 ccc, then in the program stopped at 'insert' code showing that **'raise errors.InternalError("Unread result found.")**

```
curQuery3 = db.cursor()
```

When I use  **curQuery3 = db.cursor(buffered=true)**, I can only see 'aaa' and 'bbb', then nothing is displayed. Program just seems to be unresponsive. Any help will be appreciated!!

```
print('aaa')
sql = "SELECT * FROM my_original_table"
curQuery3.execute(sql)

print('bbb')

for row in curQuery3:
   print('ccc')
   print(row)
   dat = list(row)
   id = dat.pop(0)
   eye = dat.pop(0) 
   sql = "INSERT INTO new_table VALUES ( '%s', '%s' );" % (id, eye)
   curExe.execute(sql)
```

Comment: From the manual: "For nonbuffered cursors, rows are not fetched from the server until a row-fetching method is called. In this case, you must be sure to fetch all rows of the result set before executing any other statements on the same connection".

Comment: Showed some ideas here yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38351885

Comment: Hey.. Any solutions on this? I am also facing the same problem nto knowing what to do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python MySQL connector - unread result found when using fetchone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29772337/python-mysql-connector-unread-result-found-when-using-fetchone)

Answer (score 3):

Try by passing `buffered = true` in your cursor. Read more official [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-tutorial-cursorbuffered.html)

```
cursor = conn.cursor(buffered=True)
```