# I keep getting the error 'unread result found', no matter what I change

Tags: python, sql

The code is given below which attempts to insert a value into the database and create one and insert if not available according to the usernames of the users. 
I keep getting an error 'Unread result found' on the line highlighted with a comment below.
Thank you in advance!

```
def update_userDatabase(username,text_input):
    available = False
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="1234",database="ChatBot")
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    mycursor.execute("SHOW TABLES")
    result = mycursor.fetchone()
    sg.popup()

    if text_input == "":
        for x in result:
            sg.popup(x)
            if x == username:
                available = True

        if available == True:
            sql = """INSERT INTO {tab} (Date) VALUES (%s)""".format(tab=username)
            val = (now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
            mycursor.execute(sql, val)
        else:
            sql = """CREATE TABLE {tab} (Date varchar(50),Questions varchar(20))""".format(tab=username)
            mycursor.execute(sql)
            sql = """INSERT INTO {tab} (Date) VALUES (%s)""".format(tab=username)
            val = (now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
            *mycursor.execute(sql, val)* #THIS IS THE LINE WITH THE ERROR

    elif username=="":
        sql = "INSERT INTO %s (Questions) VALUES (%s)"
        val = (text_input)
        mycursor.execute(sql, val)
```

Comment: I just want to point out that because of the way you're formatting your strings, this code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. See https://realpython.com/prevent-python-sql-injection/

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38350816/python-mysql-connector-internalerror-unread-result-found-when-close-cursor - you might want to close your cursor once done and provide the parameter `buffered=True` when you're opening it.

Comment: But it still gives the same error, despite closing the cursor and adding buffered=true