# Sqlalchemy - Error closing cursor Traceback with InternalError : Unread result found

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, aws-lambda, amazon-aurora

I am using sqlalchemy to save data to a mysql database in rds (aurora-serverless).This is being done with a lambda function.

Everything is working fine except the fact that whenever a new lamdba container is initialized, I get the following error. After which everything runs smoothly again unless a new container is created. From whatever I understand, somehow the unread result from the cursor in the old container retains itself and when it tries to one a new container at the initialisation step it tries to somehow close an old cursor and then it throws this exception.

I am creating the engine and the sessionmaker on the global level of my lambda and creating a session and destroying it one each call to my handler.

```
[ERROR] 2019-08-28T13:37:22.454Z    Error closing cursor
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1338, in _safe_close_cursor
cursor.close()
File "/var/task/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 402, in close
self._cnx.handle_unread_result()
File "/var/task/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 695, in handle_unread_result
raise errors.InternalError("Unread result found")
mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found
```

Any help in this regard would be really helpful.

Following is a code snippet to help understand the lambda within which this error is thrown

```
def connect_db():
    def connect():
        return mysql.connector.connect(host=hostname, user=username, password=password, database=database, port=port)

    db = create_engine(f'mysql+mysqlconnector://', creator=connect, isolation_level='SERIALIZABLE', echo=False)
    return db


# establish connection once per container
engine = connect_db()
Data.__table__.create(bind=engine, checkfirst=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

def save_to_database(data):
    session = Session()
    try:
        ids = [result[0] for result in session.query(Data.id).all()]
        ...
        #saving logic
        ...
        session.bulk_insert_mappings(Data, insert_data)
        session.flush()

        session.bulk_update_mappings(Data, update_data)
        session.flush()

        session.commit()

    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()

def handler(event, context):
    output = save_to_database(event)
    return {'records': output}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be related to a Cursor having remaining rows that weren’t exhausted when it is being closed. The typical case for this issue is when you do a Select query, uses fetchone() and don’t consume the rest of the rows (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29774476/6203472), but that would imply that you have another piece of code than the bulk insert showed in your question. For some reason the driver doesn’t like that and you must consume the whole cursor (calling fetchall() before closing the cursor or using a buffered cursor)

Comment: My bad, forgot to include the select query for all ids int he table, but it seems i am doing a fetchall an not fetchone, updated my question accordingly