# Python MySQL many function show InternalError: Unread result found

Tags: python, database, mysql-python

I create function function1_db() use to get latest id from column j_id and function2_read() use to insert new data. Each function have to connect to MySQL database like this.

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="xxxxxxxxxxx",
  user="xxx",
  passwd="xxxxxx",
  database="test_db"
)


def function1_db():

    last_id = 0 

    mycursor = mydb.cursor()

    sql = "SELECT * FROM log ORDER BY j_id DESC"

    mycursor.execute(sql)
    result = mycursor.fetchone()

    mycursor.close()

    if result != None:

        last_id = result[4]

    return last_id

def function2_read(last_id):

    mycursor = mydb.cursor()

    res = "xxx"
    if not res.empty:

        sql = "INSERT INTO log (id, user, number, time, j_id, alert) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
        val = [(None, res['User'], res['Pages'] , res['State'], last_id, 0 )]

        mycursor.executemany(sql, val)

        mydb.commit()

        print(mycursor.rowcount, "was inserted.") 

        mycursor.close()
```

whe I run this code it's show error like this. How to fix it ?

```
    raise errors.InternalError("Unread result found")

InternalError: Unread result found
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set Buffered = true ([from related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29772337/python-mysql-connector-unread-result-found-when-using-fetchone))

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)
```