# Problems getting data from mysql database to ios app using flask get method

Tags: ios, mysql, json, swift, flask

I am trying to send my ios app a josn file containing my entire mysql database using flask's http get method. When I call my server, I receive this error:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [29/May/2020 20:40:43] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
[2020-05-29 20:40:43,694] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tjdalessandro/Desktop/ROOT/MEEP/PythonTests/app.py", line 52, in register
    result = mycursor.execute(result)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 234, in execute
    self._cnx.handle_unread_result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 712, in handle_unread_result
    raise errors.InternalError("Unread result found")
mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found
```

I'd like to know how to modify the following app.py file and swift file to recieve a json file of my data base inside my ios app

app.py(also contains a working post method)

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import make_response
from flask import request, jsonify
import mysql.connector

#opens database connectionto "events" database
try:
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="Pass", database = "events")
    print("Connection OK")

except e:
    print("Connection failed: ", e)
#prepare a cursor object using cursor() method

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        event_id = request.form['a']
        poi = request.form['b']
        address = request.form['c']
        start_time = request.form['d']
        end_time = request.form['e']

        sql = "INSERT INTO events (event_id, poi, address, start_time, end_time) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
        val = (event_id, poi, address, start_time, end_time)


        try:
           # Execute the SQL command
           mycursor.execute(sql, val)
           # Commit your changes in the database
           mydb.commit()
           mydb.close()
        except e:
           # Rollback in case there is any error
           print("Error: ", e)
           mydb.rollback()

        return make_response("Success!", 200)

    elif request.method == 'GET':

        result = "SELECT * FROM events;"

        try:
           # Execute the SQL command
           result = mycursor.execute(result)
           # Commit your changes in the database
           mydb.commit()
           mydb.close()
        except e:
           # Rollback in case there is any error
           print("Error: ", e)
           mydb.rollback()

        return make_response(jsonify(result=result), 200)

print("DB is closed")
```

datafetcher.swift

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

let apiUrl = "http://localhost:5000/"

class DataFetcher: ObservableObject {

    @Published var events: [eventdata] = []

    func fetchEvents(){
        events.removeAll()
        let url = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: apiUrl)! as URL)

        url.httpMethod = "GET"

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url as URLRequest) { (data, response, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print(err.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { return }
            if response.statusCode == 200 {
                guard let data = data else { return }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    do{
                        self.events = try JSONDecoder().decode([eventdata].self, from: data)
                    }catch let err {
                        print("Error: \(err)")
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("HTTPURLResponse code: \(response.statusCode)")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: are cursors reusable like that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29772337/python-mysql-connector-unread-result-found-when-using-fetchone

Comment: @DaveAnkin I changed it to  mycursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True) and still no difference

Comment: what happens if you make new cursor every connection?

Comment: @DaveAnkin i tried that too but and it didn't help with the get request but I think you are right since I cannot make both a get and post request in the same instance of the server(this didn't help with that either though)