# Keep getting mysql.connector : Unread result found

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python

Tried different things,even added buffered=True keep getting Unread result found
https://hastebin.com/ebimukafas.py

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python3732\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/aron/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/scratch_3.py", line 41, in add_to_db
    cursor.execute(command,values)
  File "C:\Users\aron\PycharmProjects\new\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 521, in execute
    self._connection.handle_unread_result()
  File "C:\Users\aron\PycharmProjects\new\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 1059, in handle_unread_result
    raise errors.InternalError("Unread result found")
mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found
```

Comment: Post the full Traceback of the error

Comment: Okay,  posted it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python MySQL connector - unread result found when using fetchone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29772337/python-mysql-connector-unread-result-found-when-using-fetchone)

Comment: No it doesn't, I am unable to add data to database

Comment: Anyone? I'm stuck at this from two days

Comment: Can you share some code?