# mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found

Tags: python-3.x

input:

```
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
                               port="3306",
                               user="root",
                               database="database_name")

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT asin FROM table_name LIMIT 5")
for i in cursor:
    cursor.execute(f"UPDATE table_name SET `barkod` = '123321' WHERE `table_name`.`asin` = '{i}'")
```

output:

> mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found

Comment: You need to read the results of the select query (for example, by calling `cursor.fetchall()`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python MySQL connector - unread result found when using fetchone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29772337/python-mysql-connector-unread-result-found-when-using-fetchone)