# Python Msql Unread result found

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I got this error while trying to get variable from a DataBase in MySql

```
0x000002A MySQL Connection Error!
```

MySql error is provided when version/value we're trying to get from database is not a number

output when trying to print value Program is trying to get from database:
`None`

I tried to get variable named: "gameVersion" from DataBase Named: "gameversions", using Name of game but Instead of getting variable which has: "beta" I got mysql connector error

file and code that caused this error: functions.py:

```
import mysql.connector

database = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    passwd = "s+W2DrcPQK5dada2^!dV!RUSZ@2$PbEX*3eacT",
    database = "PythonDB",
)

my_cursor = database.cursor(buffered=True)

user = ""
game = ""
db_version = my_cursor.execute(f"SELECT gameVersion FROM gameversions WHERE gameName = 'Grand Thiefs'")

sqlStuff = "INSERT INTO users (usersUid, usersEmail, usersPwd, UsersPerms, usersMoney, gameVersion) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
sqlStuffv = "INSERT INTO gameversions (gameVersion, gameName) VALUES (%s, %s)"

def CreateDataBase(name):
    my_cursor.execute(f"CREATE DATABASE {name}")

#my_cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE gameVersions (gameVersion varchar(255) NOT NULL, gameName varchar(255) NOT NULL);")
def ShowTables():
    my_cursor.execute("SHOW TABLES")

def ShowDataBases():
    my_cursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")

def CreateUser(Name, Password, Email, Version):
    global user
    user = [{Name}, {Email}, {Password}, "User", "0", {Version}]
    my_cursor.execute(sqlStuff, user)
    database.commit()

def checkversion(version, name):
    if version != db_version:
        if type(db_version) == float:
            return "Failure"
        else:
            return "MySQL Connection Error"
    else:
        return "Correct"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python MySQL connector - unread result found when using fetchone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29772337/python-mysql-connector-unread-result-found-when-using-fetchone)

Comment: Can you add your code to find an answer ?

Comment: Added my code @Soralienne

Comment: I solved my problem with error but got a bug and the code returns "none" twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by changing code from:

```
def checkversion(version):
    #! Code Does Not Work Due To db_version error returning "None"!
    my_cursor.execute("SELECT gameVersion FROM gameversions WHERE gameName='Grand Thiefs' limit 1;")
    if version != db_version:
        if type(db_version) != str or float:
            #print(db_version)
            return "Failure"
        else:
            #print(db_version)
            return "MySQL Connection Error"
    else:
        return "Correct"
```

To:

```
def checkversion(version):
    my_cursor.execute("SELECT gameVersion FROM gameversions")
    db_version = my_cursor.fetchone()
    if version != db_version[0]:
        if not type(db_version) in [str, float]:
            print(db_version)
            return "Failure"
        else:
            #print(db_version)
            return "MySQL Connection Error"
    else:
        return "Correct"
```

Thanks to youtube tutorial Help is not needed anymore

Answer (score 0):

My code to connect at MySQL is :

```
connection = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="root",
    port="8889",
    database="registration",
    auth_plugin="mysql_native_password"
)

c = connection.cursor()
```

Make sure you are connected to Mamp, Xampp, Wamp and others but try this to connect

Comment: I watched this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yOmxJbZjTnU
So I don't use Xampp, Mamp, Or wamp :I

Comment: You are on Easy-Php ? Did you use the right path-file in your "php launcher" ?

Comment: Give discord Cuz Im dumb

Comment: Okay : Hellgame#1922

Comment: Sent invite to you