# SQL errors in dash Callbacks for dynamic dropdowns

Tags: sql, mysql, callback, dropdown, plotly-dash

I'm trying to update the dropdown's content dynamically based on another dropdown's value in dash python.
I have implemented the above task as callback which updates the content.
I am able to update the second dropdown [gp_dropdown] but unable to update the driver dropdown and getting few SQL errors.

Below is my code and the errors I get

```
import dash
from dash import dcc, html, callback, Output, Input, State
import plotly.express as px
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import fastf1

from pages.side_bar import sidebar, topbar
from pages.track import bar
import mysql.connector
from pprint import pprint

db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="",
    database="f1"
)

## gp dropdown
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM events_2021")
event_schedule_result = cur.fetchall()
event_names = []
for row in event_schedule_result:
    event_names.append(row[5])
print(event_names)

## driver dropdown
cur.execute("select * from 2021_round_1_bahrain_grand_prix_race;")
driver_result = cur.fetchall()
driver_names = []
for row in driver_result:
    driver_names.append(row[5] + ' ' + row[6])

fastf1.Cache.enable_cache(r'D:\F1 PROJECT')

dash.register_page(__name__, path='/explore')

CONTENT_STYLE = {
    "margin-left": "16rem",
    "margin-right": "2rem",
    "padding": "1rem 1rem",
}

df = fastf1.get_event_schedule(2021, include_testing=False)

year_dropdown_pie = dcc.Dropdown([2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022], 2018, id='year-dropdown-pie')
year_dropdown = dcc.Dropdown([2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022], 2018, id='year-dropdown')
gp_dropdown = dcc.Dropdown(event_names, 'Bahrain Grand Prix', id='gp-dropdown')
# gp_dropdown_track = dcc.Dropdown(event_names, 'Bahrain Grand Prix', id='gp-dropdown-track')
driver_dropdown = dcc.Dropdown(driver_names, 'Lewis Hamilton', id='driver-dropdown')
# year_dropdown_track = dcc.Dropdown([2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022], 2018, id='year-dropdown-track')

pie_fig_2018 = go.Figure(go.Sunburst())

team_content = html.Div(id="page-content", children=[year_dropdown_pie, dcc.Graph(figure=pie_fig_2018, id='sunburst')],
                        style=CONTENT_STYLE)
driver_content = html.Div(id="page-content", children=[year_dropdown, gp_dropdown, driver_dropdown],
                          style=CONTENT_STYLE)
# track_content = html.Div(id="page-content",
#                          children=[year_dropdown_track, gp_dropdown_track, dcc.Graph(id="track_plot")],
#                          style=CONTENT_STYLE)

# tabs
tab1_content = dbc.Card(
    dbc.CardBody(
        [
            team_content
        ]
    ),
    className="mt-3",
)

tab2_content = dbc.Card(
    dbc.CardBody(
        [
            driver_content
        ]
    ),
    className="mt-3",
)

tab3_content = dbc.Card(
    dbc.CardBody(
        [
            #bar()
        ]
    ),
    className="mt-3",
)

tabs = dbc.Tabs(
    [
        dbc.Tab(tab1_content, label="Teams"),
        dbc.Tab(tab2_content, label="Drivers"),
        dbc.Tab(tab3_content, label="Tracks"),
    ]
)

content = html.Div(id="page-content", children=[tabs],
                   style=CONTENT_STYLE)

layout = html.Div([
    sidebar(),
    content

])
```

The below callback for the first dropdown works fine

```
@callback(
    Output('gp-dropdown', 'options'),
    Input('year-dropdown', 'value')
)
def update_gp_dropdown(year):
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM {}".format('events_' + str(year)))
    event_schedule_result = cur.fetchall()
    print('hello')
    event_names = []
    for row in event_schedule_result:
        event_names.append(row[5])
    return event_names
```

But when I add this code as the callback for second dropdown errors creep in

```
@callback(
    Output('driver-dropdown', 'options'),
    Input('gp-dropdown', 'value'),
    State('year-dropdown', 'value')
)
def update_driver_dropdown(gp, year):
    query = "SELECT round_number FROM {} WHERE event_name = '{}'".format('events_' + str(year), gp)
    print(query)
    cur.execute(query)
    round_num = cur.fetchall()
    round_num = round_num[0][0]
    print(round_num)
    gp = gp.relace(' ', '_')
    cur.execute("select * from {};".format(str(year) + '_round_' + str(round_num) + '_' + gp + '_race'))
    driver_result = cur.fetchall()
    driver_names = []
    for row in driver_result:
        driver_names.append(row[5] + ' ' + row[6])
    print(driver_names)
    return driver_names
```

I get the following error when i add both the callbacks

```
line 227, in update_driver_dropdown
    cur.execute(query)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 303, in execute
    self._cnx.handle_unread_result()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 921, in handle_unread_result
    raise InternalError("Unread result found")
mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found
```

Comment: Did you try to use a [buffered cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33632767/2529954) ?